# What is Meta Key for Ubuntu on Mac?

Tags: keyboard

I have Ubuntu installed on Mac. What is the Meta Key on Mac keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

On my Macbook Pro (el capitan), the meta key is by default mapped to the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.

For example, say in emacs editor, to do a `M-%` ([emacs find and replace](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Query-Replace.html)), I would do <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>%</kbd>

(I've tested this on iTerm2 and Terminal app.)

This [Stackoverflow forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856437/command-key-as-meta-key-in-os-x-terminal-app/45896663#45896663) helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You can check in **System -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Layout -> Options ->Alt/Win key behavior** if you are running a GUI, but it is probably defaulted to the option key on a Mac.

If you prefer command line, you can use `xev` to check what each key is mapped to.

Comment: How can I find this setting in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I am also having trouble finding this in Ubuntu 16.04