# How to enable the Meta key on 16.04? Switching from OSX and having hotkey issues

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, macosx, intellij

I'm trying to make the switch from Mac to Ubuntu but I've become really attached to my IntelliJ keybindings which has a profile for OSX.

The problem is that when I enable the OSX profile it's asking for Meta+W to close a window when it used to be CMD+W. But as far as I can work out there is no Meta key enabled by default in Ubuntu and the directions posted previously don't work in 16.04.

I already tried the directions here: [What is Meta Key for Ubuntu on Mac?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902630/what-is-meta-key-for-ubuntu-on-mac) without any luck.

Any ideas? I saw other posts mentioning using something like `xmodmap` to permanently rebind the key(s) but that seems like overkill for a newbie so I was hoping for something a little more approachable / configurable out of the box.

Comment: We are soldiers in the same trench, looking for the same answer.

Comment: @ShawnLu I gave up and just started doing custom hotkeys for everything. In another year or so I should have most of them worked out and at that point it might be worth it to share my profile with Idea / the world. But right now linux hotkeys are in a sad state of affairs for IntelliJ.